# Google Search API: 'Index' object has no attribute 'put' when running locally

Tags: python, google-app-engine

Using the experimental Google Search API for App Engine and running locally:

```
search.Index(name=_INDEX_NAME).put(document_to_index)
```

This is exactly as per the Google documentation here: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/search/overview

But generates the following error:

> AttributeError: 'Index' object has no attribute 'put'

Is this a bug or have I missed something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to update your SDK. `add` was deprecated in favor of `put` in release 1.7.3.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the function has been re-named 'add'. This worked fine:

```
search.Index(name=_INDEX_NAME).add(document_to_index)
```

Comment: Are you using the most recent SDK? The add method has been deprecated in favour of put.

Comment: Please don't do this, as eventually we'll remove `add` and your code will stop working. See my answer below.